# Error occur when I try to run command npm start in visual studio code using powershell and command prompt

Tags: powershell

Error when I run command npm start in vscode using powershell

```
Starting the development server...

node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAGwAbwBjAGEAbABoAG8AcwB0ADoAMwAwADAAMAAiAA=='
  ]
}
```

I try to start run command npm start to run react js project

Comment: ENOENT is no entry.  Code is trying to execute a method in a dll and the method either does not exist or there is no entry point for the method (not public).

Comment: Your encoded command is : Start "http://localhost:3000"  Do you have a port 3000 running?